# JWT payload does not contain the required claims

Tags: laravel, api, jwt

I needed a token that will never expire i.e it will have a lifetime validity. So, I changed the following in `jwt.php` file in `config` folder.

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', null),
```

But after this action I started getting erros saying: `Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException: JWT payload does not contain the required claims in file apiTest/vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Validators/PayloadValidator.php on line 65`.

Comment: Bad, very bad practice.

Comment: @Maksim Help me with more information please? What is very bad practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is occuring because `required_claims`is expecting the `exp`. So just remove `exp` key from your `config/jwt.php's` `required_claims` array like.

```
    'required_claims' => [
    'iss',
    'iat',
    // 'exp',  
    'nbf',
    'sub',
    'jti',
],
```

In my case I just commented the `exp` line and this will solve the problem.

A issue was created on github regarding this issue. You can find it [here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/176). Here you will get solution to this problem and similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for not expiring login in JWTAuth:

1. Open `jwt.php` in config folder (if it not available then publish the `jwt.php` file using this command in project==>

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuthProviders\JWTAuthServiceProvider" )`

2. Change

`'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 60),`
to

`'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', null),`

3. remove exp in this line:-

`'required_claims' => [ 'iss', 'iat', 'exp', 'nbf', 'sub', 'jti', ],`

4. After this fire this command on terminal inside your project

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```